# VBS Not writing text to webpage

Tags: html, vbscript, execution

I have the following VBS code in my webpage:

```
<body>

<%

Randomize
response.write(Rnd)

%>

</body>
```

But instead of outputting a random number, I get a webpage that says this:

```
<% Randomize response.write(Rnd) %>
```

Why won't my code execute?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your webpage extension is managed by the ASP handler mapping. The steps to configure handler mappings depend on the version of IIS you are using.

See [this page](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis) for information on configuring ASP under IIS 7 or 7.5.